# t.tBodies(0).appendChild(r) is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

`t.tBodies(0).appendChild(r);` is not working in firefox. This is javascript code and used to create dynamic table elements. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
t.tBodies(0).appendChild(r);
```

With:

```
t.tBodies[0].appendChild(r);
```

Does it work?